# JavaFX: supporting different resolutions

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to understand how to support different resolutions in JavaFX. I'm looking for a sort of a guide about how to achieve this.

I want to create an application which requires a minimum resolution of, for example, 1280×720. And I want that my applications looks fine on any higher resolution too (like 1920×1080). Also, the application should look good at different DPI values.
How can I do that?

Lets set as minimum requirements JDK 11.0.2+ and JavaFX 11.0.2+ to be more specific.

What I (seem to) understand now:

1. Minimum width and height of the stage have to be set.
2. I can not bother about DPI support, as [it seems to be implemented](https://news.kynosarges.org/2015/06/29/javafx-dpi-scaling-fixed/).

What I still don't understand:

1. How do I set the dimensions of elements, indents, etc.

   - Should I set values in pixels for the minimum supported resolution and then multiply them by the coefficient according to the current resolution?
   - Or should I build up the size as a percentage of the width/height of the screen?
   - Or should I do it all in a very different way?
2. Should I avoid any controls/layouts?

I hope I was clear enough.

I'm new to creating interfaces for real, not toy applications. And I will appreciate any help, be it comments, explanations, code samples or links to articles.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It depends on the type of application you’re creating.  If the application is comprised of standard UI elements, like buttons and text fields and tables, the answer is that you should do nothing at all:  just use layout classes and let the default preferred size calculations do the work for you.  If you’re making a game, it may be a little more complicated, depending on how much work you want to do.

Comment: @VGR I'm creating a client application that's not very complex. So yes, it is comprised of standard UI elements. But I don't quite understand the "default preferred size calculations" statement. For example, if I have a button, it needs to be sized. And this size should be different for different resolutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well that a very good question as `JavaFX` doesn't support responsive resolution on the fly so you gonna do it by yourself

1. First try to rely on the different layouts to distribute the UI components according to the computed location, width and height like in `BorderPane` that have 5 sections to set your components at effortlessly
2. After doing the first step and you still have some components that want custom modification in terms of width and height set your desirable width and height and multiply these values by a ratio this ratio you can calculate it by getting the screen resolution so the next time you run the app on a different screen with different resolution it's gonna give a different width or height for that component
3. You can also provide a different `FXML` file for each supported resolution by your app so you can run the appropriate design and also for landscape and portrait cases
4. Of course you can look for a third party library that can provide responsive component like `BootstrapFX` which is similar to that for web design and also there is `ResponsiveFX` too but I didn't try them before

I hope my answer help you or put you on the right track to make some cool apps

Answer (score 6):

Every component (button, text field, etc.) calculates its own preferred size, based on resolution, font sizes, the theme chosen by the user, and so on.  All you have to do is make sure you don’t interfere with that.  So don’t set any dimensions.

When you place components in a layout (any subclass of Pane other than AnchorPane), the layout will do its best to respect each child’s preferred size.  In most applications, you will never have to set a single width or height explicitly.

Comment: So basically all I have to set is just minimum width and height of the stage?

And what to do if I want that some components not extend past certain size? For example, labels might have different length of their text.
See [this code paste](https://pastebin.com/pVDtWLUe) and [this screenshot](http://prnt.sc/pecqb3).

Comment: You shouldn’t have to set the size of the Stage or Scene, either.  By default, the Stage size is set to the size of the Scene, and the Scene accommodates all Nodes’ preferred sizes.  If you have a Label that might contain long text, you can set its maximum size, but typically long text is placed in a TextField or TextArea, which handles long text automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I do need to set the sizes, since in some panes elements will appear dynamically, i.e. they may not appear at all. And in that case these panes won't take up any space at all. How would you recommend setting the sizes?

Comment: I don’t see why that would require your setting sizes.  If you don’t want a pane to appear, call `setVisible(false)` on it.

Comment: I need something different. I would like a pane to appear, even if there are no elements on it at all.

Comment: I suspect you want a StackPane, which contains both a blank node and the regular user interface.  I can’t say for sure without more information about what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to use different fxml-Files:

MaximizedPane.fxml: --> see prefWidth  / perfHight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.stage.Screen?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           prefWidth="${screen.visualBounds.width}" 
           prefHeight="${screen.visualBounds.height}" >
    <fx:define>
        <Screen fx:factory="getPrimary" fx:id="screen"/>
    </fx:define>
    <Label text="A maximized pane"/>    
</StackPane>
```

Load the fxml-files dynamicly:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MaximizedFXMLPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MaximizedPane.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Example from my git archive: https://github.com/src-mgra/my-calendar/blob/master/MyCalendar/src/sample/Main.java

---

Another way is to use scenes:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScreenResolutionDemo extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth() / 3;
        double height = screenSize.getHeight() / 2;

        try {
            **primaryStage.setScene**(new Scene(new AnchorPane(), *width*, **height**));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building a desktop application with pretty much the same constraints. I faced this question a month ago but later on found out that I need not do anything. 
The `Pane` will automatically resize the internal elements as per the screen resolution. As correctly mentioned by VGR that Anchorpane will not do this resizing of child elements and I need to replace all Anchorpane with Pane.

Another issue was faced at one of the test machine that the stage were being displayed too large for the low resolution display and wasn't being resized automatically. 
To resolve this, I set the resolution of the screen to another value and then switched it back to the original value and it got fixed.

You will need to set the minimum and(or) maximum size of the stage and(maybe) set it non-resizable and that must work.